# override bootstrap @media breakpoint

Tags: javascript, html, css, sass

I am very new at this stuff, so please bear with me.

I have been messing around views recently and was wondering if it's possible to override the breakpoints stored in the bootstrap.

ie)

```
:root {
--breakpoint-xs: 0;
--breakpoint-sm: 576px;
--breakpoint-md: 768px;
--breakpoint-lg: 992px;
--breakpoint-xl: 1200px;
}
```

specifically, I'd like to override the --breakpoint-md setting. I've noticed similar questions have been asked, but the answers weren't clear. from what I see, these become variables that are used in specific instances. I'd like the setting to apply to the entire site. Is this possible?

To explain a bit. When I change the screen size my columns stack at 767px, which is the look I'm going for at 768px, but at 768px the views are squished ugly. I have been reading about scss a bit, is that the only solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using bootstrap scss, then use the below.

First You have to install boostrap

```
npm install bootstrap
```

And then you can set custom breakpoints.

```
@import '../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/functions';
@import '../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/variables';

$grid-columns:      12;
$grid-gutter-width: 1.5rem;

$grid-breakpoints: (
    xs: 0,
    vs: 300px,
    sm: 500px,
    md: 750px,
    lg: 1000px,
    vl: 1300px,
    xl: 1600px
);

$container-max-widths: (
  xs: 299px,
  vs: 499px,
  sm: 749px,
  md: 999px,
  lg: 1299px,
  vl: 1599px,
  xl: 1999px
);

@import '../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss';
```

Comment: So, I've done all this, the console isn't showing errors, and my sass seems to be compiled based on the Live Sass Compile. But the view isn't breaking at the expected point for me. Is there anything I can provide for further information?

Comment: Did you check the breakpoints on the inspect window?

Comment: I'm not completely sure what you mean by that. I see in the 'styles' window that a call is coming from 'custom.scss' for the breakpoint and it appears to be crossed out in _root.scss. This leads me to believe the code is working behind the scenes and overriding the code from root. But the change doesn't see to make any difference.

Comment: If those styles are applied to your components, then it will make a big difference. Now I am using it on my project with the code I wrote.

Comment: You can easily check that on https://develop.soundblock.arena.com signin page. Here I used col-md-7. I set md as 750px, so you can check that on that live page.

Comment: Awesome! That did it for me! Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You can customize anything you'd like to with bootstrap.

To get started, take a look at the documentation on customization here: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/customize/overview/

Your best bet would be to use sass, as documented here: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/customize/sass/

Something like this in your custom.scss file.

```
// Custom.scss
// Option A: Include all of Bootstrap

// Include any default variable overrides here (though functions won't be available)

@import "../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";

// Then add additional custom code here

:root {
--breakpoint-md: 768px;
}
```